# How to change the an HDF5 table title (created using pytables)

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

I was wondering if there was a way to change the title of an `HDF5 table`, that I created in my python code, using `pyTables`. I gave the wrong title string, and I need too change it now, so when I open it again in python, I can distinguish it from other tables that I load, according to its title.

Answer (score 0):

How about you change the `_v_title` attribute on the `Node` and then save the hdf5 file again?

`table._v_title = 'new title'`

Comment: `table.title = 'new title'` is sufficient.